# Receiving mails thru Gmail with VB.NET

Tags: gmail-api, attachment

I am using VB.Net. I can download emails thru the Gmail API, but it loads mails with the attachments, which can be very large hence the process is slow.
How can I download mails without the attachment and when needed, I can click on the mail and get the attachment.

Thanks

Comment: Please share some code.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.